# Linq to Entity Groupby and concatinate column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Thats my Entity Model

```
 public class Warning
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string WarningCId { get; set; }
            public int WarningYearCounter { get; set; }
            public string NavalDepartment { get; set; }
            public string MiscellaneousInfo { get; set; }
            public EmergencyType EmergencyType { get; set; }
            public WarningType WarningType { get; set; }
            public DateTime IssuedDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
            public string WarningMessage { get; set; }
            public string WarningInfo { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }
```

Thats My repository

```
 public class WarningRepository :IWarningRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context { get; set; }

        public WarningRepository (ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


    }
```

I want to `groupby` warnings on `startDate.Year` *(which are `active == true`)* and concatenate its Column `WarningYearCounter` *(something like `group_concat` in MySQL)* Like this

```
Year    Warning
2014    1,5,6,7
2015    6,8,9,0
```

Query:

```
_context.Warnings.Where(w => w.Active == true).GroupBy(w => w.StartDate.Year)
```

Comment: What stops you from adding it?

Comment: so what's exactly wrong with the query you've provided?

Comment: @kiziu i dont know  how to concatenate column in linq to entity

Comment: @decPL how to select and concatenate column, thats missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something like this.

```
var results = (from w in _context.Warnings
               where w.Active
               group w.WarningYearCounter by w.StartDate.Year into grp
               select grp)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(g => new
              {
                  Year = g.Key,
                  Warning = string.Join(",", g)
              });
```

The string concatenation is best done outside of the DB, thus the use of `AsEnumerable`.   Also I just like to use query syntax for the part that will be translated into SQL and then switch to method syntax for the part that will be done in memory, but you can translate it all to method or query syntax if you like.

Comment: @FredrikRedin Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: @juharr Thank You Very much! It Worked :)

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq I just made a change based on Theo's answer that will reduce the amount of data that is returned from the DB.

Answer (score 4):

If you are expecting EF Linq-To-SQL to generate a SQL statement that produces those results, I don't believe it is possible. You can however get pretty close:

```
public void GetWarningsGroup(IEnumerable<Warning> warnings)
{
    var result = warnings
      //Only Active warnings
      .Where(w => w.Active)
      //Grouped By year - Selecting the WarningYearCounter
      .GroupBy(w => w.StartDate.Year, w => w.WarningYearCounter)
      //Force Linq-To-SQL execution
      .ToList()
      //Finally concatenate the WarningYearCounter into the result
      .Select(g => new Tuple<int, string>(g.Key, string.Join(",", g)));
}
```